# Progerssbar won't update

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to implement a progressbar in my WPF application.

So I added one to my view

```
      <ProgressBar Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="31"
               Minimum="0"
               Maximum="50"
             Value="{Binding CurrentProgress}" />
```

My ViewModel got a new property:

```
 public int CurrentProgress
{
  get { return mCurrentProgress; }
  set
  {
    if (mCurrentProgress != value)
    {
      mCurrentProgress = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
    }
  }
}
```

When my load command executes, it raises an Generated event for every file loaded.
And the EventHandler for this event adds +1 to the 'CurrentProgress' property like this:

```
private void GeneratedHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  CurrentProgress++;
}
```

But I don't see any progress on the bar. Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're performing work in the UI thread.  The UI thread can't update the UI while you're performing work in it.  You're using the thread to load files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried reproducing your problem, but it worked just fine here.

Anyway, there are a few steps that you can follow:

1. Make sure that you are not loading your files on the UI thread. If you are, take a look at *"Showing progress while performing a lengthy task"* on [**this**](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/) article.
2. Make sure the `DataContext` of your `Window` is correct, your `ViewModel` implements `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` and your `RaisePropertyChanged` method is correct.

---

Here's the code I've used (**do not copy and paste the app.xml**):

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    private int _Progress;
    public int Progress
    {
        get
        {
            return _Progress;
        }

        set
        {
            if(value != Progress)
            {
                _Progress = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ViewModel_MainWindow}">
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Minimum="0" Maximum="50" />
</Grid>
```

And the **app.xaml**:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" > <!--change the namespace to the one where you ViewModel is-->
<Application.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel_MainWindow" /> <!--important-->
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I forgot to load the work to a background thread. It's working as expected now, thanks!